# gunicorn - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'environ'

Tags: python-3.x, django, gunicorn, wsgi

I am running the Django project with `gunicorn`:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 project.wsgi
```

but I am getting the error below  :

```
[2022-10-12 12:05:11 +0300] [33444] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-10-12 12:05:11 +0300] [33444] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (33444)
[2022-10-12 12:05:11 +0300] [33444] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-10-12 12:05:11 +0300] [33446] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 33446
[2022-10-12 12:05:12 +0300] [33446] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/idris/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/idris/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/home/idris/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/idris/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/idris/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/idris/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/idris/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/idris/Documents/workspace_captiq/venv/captiq/captiq/wsgi.py", line 8, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/idris/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/home/idris/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/home/idris/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/idris/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/idris/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/idris/Documents/workspace_captiq/venv/captiq/captiq/settings.py", line 5, in <module>
    import environ
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'environ'
[2022-10-12 12:05:12 +0300] [33446] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 33446)
[2022-10-12 12:05:12 +0300] [33444] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2022-10-12 12:05:12 +0300] [33444] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

What could be the reason and the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I get this error when I forget to install https://pypi.org/project/django-environ/

```
pip install django-environ
```

Comment: Its actually already installed.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to activate your env?